# How to deploy two projects with NetBeans that use the same deployed JRE?

Tags: netbeans, deployment, java

I have two Java projects in Net Beans IDE 7.3.  One is a JavaFX GUI admin console that I've built and deployed ("admin.java"); which contains the minimized JRE and installs via a single .exe file.  The second project is a Java datalogger ("datalogger.java") that I've deployed in a /dist folder and contains "datalogger.jar" as well as a lib folder containing "apache-commons-net.jar."

The "datalogger.jar" file is dependent on settings stored in data files by "admin.java," and I want to be able to deploy it with "admin.java's" .exe file so the customer doesn't need to perform anything other than running a single .exe file to install everything.  "datalogger.java" also needs to use the same minimized JRE that is installed via "admin.java's" .exe file.

I thought of creating a .BAT file with commands to install the "datalogger.java" files to the appropriate %appdata% location(s), but this doesn't address the JRE issue.  Isn't there a way to generate a single bundle with Net Beans to accomplish all this?

Comment: Have you tried adding the resources of both projects to your bundle using the build.xml?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific @Walter?  Do you mean here:  `<fx:resources>
                <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
            </fx:resources>`  and what exactly?

Comment: Yes. I am sorry I can't help you more. I am suggesting it because Ive spent my day playing around build.xml and I believe I saw it was possible to be done through this xml (remember: I am not sure). Refer to the documentation. Hope I gave you an orientation at least.

Comment: I think you may be on the right track @Walter, but I don't know what to substitute for "${basedir}/${dist.dir}" and/or "*.jar" to get the files I need in the bundle.